# Appium for Android with multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, appium, appium-android

I am using Appium for automating my Android app. I have a fragment to enter email and after verifying that second fragment with `passwordfield` will be loaded. I am able to find all elements in the first fragment; but elements in the second fragment can't be found using any of the methods like `By`, `PageFactory` + `@AndroidFindBy`. Can someone provide a help to sort this issue?

Comment: can you share your appium log?

Answer (score 2):

Use ExplicitWait method.

```
public static void ExplicitWait(MobileElement element){
        (new WebDriverWait(driver,30)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(element));
    }
```

then before you use element of second fragment call ExplictWait

```
ExplictWait(passwordField);
passwordField.sendKeys("your password");
```